# ~/.pam_environment is not workig for root

Tags: environment-variables, pam-environment

I want to use `zsh` for `root` with `oh-my-zsh`. I already have `oh-my-zsh` cloned by my regular user, so all I need to do is to set `ZSH` env variable to that directory. So I put this in my `/root/.pam_environment`:

```
ZSH=/home/madhead/oh-my-zsh
```

That's the only string in that file. But when I try to login as root (after complete reboot) the variable is not set. I've tried both `sudo su` and `sudo -iu root`. Here is some info about software used:

```
# lsb_release -a                                                                                                                                                     
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty

# zsh --version                                                                                                                                                      
zsh 5.0.2 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Also, the same setup (`/root/.pam_environment`) works ok on my laptop with Arch Linux.

Comment: Check with `ZSH DEFAULT=/home/madhead/oh-my-zsh`

Comment: @heemayl, no, that doesn't help. `.pam_environment` should be `key=value`, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#sudo_caveat) says

> ...sudo has a default policy of resetting the Environment and setting
>   a secure path (this behavior is defined in /etc/sudoers).

And

> ...you can setup sudo not to reset certain environment variables by
>   adding some explicit environment settings to keep in /etc/sudoers.

Just do this

```
user@here:$ sudo su
root@here:$ visudo
```

And add this line:

```
Defaults env_keep += "ZSH"
```

To check if your variable exists do *exit*, than *sudo su* again and run *export* or

```
printenv ZSH
```